# When I create a database I get an error message telling me "the database already exists, choose another" when I know it doesn't

Tags: c#, database

I want to create a database but allow a user to select what folder to put it in. The code I've come with is:

```
  string dirLoc = "";

  FolderBrowserDialog fldr = new FolderBrowserDialog();
  fldr.Description = "SELECT LOCATION OF PASSWORD DATABASE\n(Recommendation: select a portable drive for security reasons.)";
  fldr.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
  fldr.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;

  if (fldr.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    dirLoc = fldr.SelectedPath;

    try
    {
      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");


      string query = "CREATE DATABASE LockKeyDB ON PRIMARY " +
        "(NAME = LakDB_Data, " +
        "FILENAME = '" + dirLoc + "\\LakDB.mdf', " +
        "SIZE = 2MB, MAXSIZE = 10MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%)" +
        "LOG ON (NAME = LakDB_Log, " +
        "FILENAME = '" + dirLoc + "\\LakDBLog.ldf', " +
        "SIZE = 1MB, MAXSIZE = 5MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%)";

      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
      conn.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      conn.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(),"LakTools - ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
```

When I run the code I get an exception thrown out like this:
[This is the error I keep getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0BEJ.jpg)

Now it looks like The SQL Server I'm using (SQL Server 2019) is saving table names because I'm still testing the program, and if I change the database name it works no problem. But, I'm still in the test mode and I don't want to keep changing the database name.

So is there anyway to get around this and clear it up?

Comment: *"when I know it doesn't"* - The database server is **usually** right about these things.  *"is saving table names because I'm still testing the program"* - If you don't think the database exists, where are you observing these tables?  *"if I change the database name it works"* - That would continue to suggest that the database exists already, because when you change the name that new one doesn't exist.  *"is there anyway to get around this"* - Either delete the existing database before trying to create it or don't try to create it?

Answer (score 1):

You are attemtpting to create different databases by separating the underlying `mdf` file in a different folders. However, you're still giving them all of the same database NAME of `LockKeyDB`.  You can't have the same database NAME multiple times on the same server, regardless of them having different storage locations.  You'll have to give each DB a unique name.

Example:

```
string query = "CREATE DATABASE " + uniquecode + "LockKeyDB ON PRIMARY " +
```